# move constructor/assignment for a trivial class in a linked list

Tags: c++, move-semantics, rule-of-five

I have a simple class with a few trivial members, and no allocations. I am planning to add a move constructor/assignment. These primitives are not going to be more effective than the normal ones.

Question one: does it make sense to do it in order to make my class more generic?

There is an internal list linking objects of the class.

Question two: what state I should leave the class that was moved from: in the list or removed from the list? I am planning to remove it from the list.

Update: there are several comments on using compiler-generated moves. I cannot do it because there is an internal list I have to take care of.

So, it is either hand-crafted moves or none. The snippet of the possible code is below, there is no multithreading.

```
class A {
 public:
  static void Run() {
       A* cur = list_;
       while(cur) {
           cur->DoWork();
           cur = cur->next_;
       }
  }
   
  virtual ~A() { Remove(); }

  A() : next_(), data_(), in_list_() {
  }

  A(int data) : next_(), data_(data), in_list() {
    Insert();
  }

  A(A const& other) : next_(), data_(other.data_), in_list() {
    Insert();
  }

  A(A&& other) : next_(), data_(other.data_), in_list() {
    other.Remove();
    Insert();
  }

  A& operator=(A const& other) {
    if (this != &other) {
       data_ = other.data_;
       Insert();
    }
    return *this;
  }

  A& operator=(A&& other) {
    if (this != &other) {
      data_ = other.data_;
      other.Remove();
      Insert();
    }
    return *this;
  }

 private:
    void DoWork() { <do-something-important-with-data>; }

    void Insert() {
      if (_in_list) {
        return;
      }
      ...;
      in_list_ = true;
    }

    void Remove() {
      if (!_in_list) {
        return;
      }
      ...;
      in_list_ = false;
    };

  A* next_;
  int data_;
  bool in_list_;

  static A* list_;
};
```

Comment: Don't add any of those (copy/move constructor/assignment) unless there is a need for them. Not sure what you mean by "more generic", but reimplementing class-functions that the compiler would generate for you without doing anything useful makes no sense to me.

Comment: one question per question please. And please show the code rather than describing it

Comment: I suppose you mean "efficient" not "effective"

Comment: Question two sounds like you haven't understood move semantics.

Comment: make sure to also read about the rule of zero.

Comment: Moving a trivial type is no different than copying it.  The default compiler-generated copy/move constructors and copy/move assignment operators will suffice.

Comment: in other words, a move does already fall back to a copy. There is no point in making your class implement that fallback behavior again.

Comment: Educational Viewing well worth the time: [Howard Hinnant's Everything You Need To Know About Move Semantics presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vLinb2fgkHk)

Comment: Probably enough in that example, but a general recommendation is to lose the `...`s and provide an example code people can drop into their tools and play with. It's surprising what neat stuff people can come back with if you give a complete example. But don't go overboard; adhere to [mre].

Comment: @user4581301 My question is not "how to do it?". My question is does it make sense?

Comment: Your design is flawed to begin with. An object should not need to care about whether it is part of a list. Also, limiting yourself to a single list is far from generic.

Comment: @molbdnilo Sorry, the application requirement is to have objects in the list.

Comment: @uuu777 Of course the objects need be in the list. That does not imply either that there is just one list or that you need a flag to keep track of whether the node is part of any list or not.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After discussion in the comments (thank you, everybody) it seems that I can answer this question myself: (1) it is a good idea to implement the rule-of-five just to support the unique_ptr, (2) the source object of the move should not be in the list after the move is done.